# how to make Windows server 2012R2 NIC connect to trunk,but with a VLAN ID

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, vlan, trunk

Windows Server 2012R2 ,with hyper-v.
for hyper-v 's guest os connecting to multi vlan, host 's NIC connect to trunk port on switch hub.
but I want set host os with VLAN ID(VLAN 10) ,for with a VLAN 10 IP address.

Comment: Tried to tag the VLAN in the guest OS NIC ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the virtual switch properties you can set a VLAN ID for the host OS:

[image]